# rpm build .spec del my program config dir when updating

Tags: linux, centos

uniin-cluster-agent is my program and `etc` is my program config.

`/usr/bin/uniin-cluster-agent -c /etc/unilin_cluster_agent/config.yml`

This is the start command

```
Name: uniin-cluster-agent
Version: %{?agent_version}
Release: %{?dist}

Summary: uniin-cluster-agent servcie
Group: Applications/System
License: xxx


%description





%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_bindir}
cp uniin-cluster-agent %{buildroot}%{_bindir}
cp -r etc %{buildroot}


%clean
rm -rf %{_builddir}/*

%files
%{_bindir}/uniin-cluster-agent
/etc/unilin_cluster_agent/*
/etc/systemd/system/uniin-cluster-agent.service

%post
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable uniin-cluster-agent.service
systemctl restart uniin-cluster-agent.service

%preun
systemctl stop uniin-cluster-agent.service
systemctl disable uniin-cluster-agent.service

%postun
systemctl daemon-reload
rm -rf /etc/unilin_cluster_agent
```

Install is well, but when I update use `rpm -Uvh xxx.rpm`

I can see that system install my new version rpm and then clean and remove old version.
But it also remove the dir `/etc/unilin_cluster_agent` and `/usr/bin/uniin-cluster-agent`, after updating.

I don't know why?

Comment: You have a `rm -rf /etc/unilin_cluster_agent` in `%postun`. `%postun` runs after your new package is installed, so it deletes the new `/etc/unilin_cluster_agent` file/dir.

Comment: @omajid it means that %postun will run when updating the rpm package not only uninstalling ? I'm not sure the order or the process it run when updating.

Comment: Yup, it's run on upgrade too. https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#ordering

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things I noticed. I could target the advice better if I knew what version of CentOS this was.

- `Group: Applications/System` is obsolete and isn't needed.
- `%clean` and `rm -rf %{_builddir}/*` is generally implied, at least in recent CentOS/Fedora/RHEL versions. You can probably leave it out
- You should own the cluster agent directory (along with children) in `%files`. I would change `/etc/unilin_cluster_agent/*` to `/etc/unilin_cluster_agent`. That says "own the directory and everything in it. A nice benefit is that when the package is uninstalled, the file/directory will automatically be deleted.
- Configuration files (those being installed under `/etc/`) should be marked as `%config` (or `%config(noreplace)`). See [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejw35/docs/rpm_config.html) for details on what they mean and which one addresses your use case better.
- `%pre`, `%post`, `%preun` and `%postun` have completely unintuitive ordering. All of these will run during package upgrades. See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#ordering for the ordering.
- To actually detect upgrades/uninstalls correctly, you should test the value of `$1` while running the scripts. The value is the number of packages that will be left on the system when the operations (install, upgrade, remove) completes. See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_syntax for complete details.
- For systemd commands, you should test with `$1` to see if the package is being installed for the first time, upgraded or removed to decide which exact systemd command to run. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd_Packaging_Draft#Scriptlets has an example set of things you might want to do. For example, if this is an upgrade, you want to `daemon-reload` and `restart` (or `try-restart`?).
- In general, never `rm -rf` during `%post` and friends. The files should have been managed by RPM itself and the should be removed by RPM. Your scripts shouldn't be touching them unless you know exactly what you are doing.